# jquery addClass and removeClass is not working in IE 11 browser?

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
<div class="files" id="files">
   <span class="sun-span"> <i class="icon ts-icon-paper-clip"></i> File
    <input title=" " type="file" class="files" name="File" id="file" multiple="multiple">
  </span> 

        <div id="FileInfoMsg" class="file-infomsg">
            You can upload a maximum of 5 files
        </div>

        <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit"
                    id="submitData">

        </button>
    </div>



<script>
    $(#submitData).click(function() {
        $('#FileInfoMsg').addClass('file-infoError').removeClass('fileinfomsg');   
    });
    </script>
```

above snippet is working in other browser addClass & remove class in jquery. but in IE 11 is not working.

Comment: On a side note, you've not wrapped `#submitData` in quotes. IE may create a problem here.

Answer (score 2):

It **not** only in IE you frogot `' '`  to `#submitData`

```
  $('#submitData').click(function() {
        $('#FileInfoMsg').addClass('file-infoError').removeClass('fileinfomsg');   
    });
```

Comment: Tell me if it helps

Answer (score 2):

Self close your input, and add quotes to `$('#submitData')`.
Your div has the class `file-infomsg` but you are removing `fileinfomsg`.

Also, be sure to allow the execution of Scripts in IE11 (it's an additional setting, should be a popup banner on the lower part of the window).

```
<div class="files" id="files">
    <span class="sun-span">
        <i class="icon ts-icon-paper-clip"></i>
        File
        <input title=" " type="file" class="files" name="File" id="file" multiple="multiple" />
    </span> 

    <div id="FileInfoMsg" class="file-infomsg">
        You can upload a maximum of 5 files
    </div>

    <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" id="submitData">
        Submit
    </button>
</div>

<script>
    $('#submitData').click(function() {
        $('#FileInfoMsg').addClass('file-infoError').removeClass('file-infomsg');   
    });
</script>
```

Comment: addClass and removeClass  is not working in IE.  the Script  is verified with putting alerts ..

Comment: @RaviR in IE11? See https://i.imgur.com/ysivaEI.png and https://i.imgur.com/l5a6jOt.png

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to add a quote to your id object `$('#submitData')`. You can use double quotes as well.

```
$('#submitData').click(function() {
    $('#FileInfoMsg').addClass('file-infoError').removeClass('fileinfomsg');   
});
```